# webpack : css points to wrong image folder in prod

Tags: css, image, webpack

When I build my project for production I get this structure :

```
build/static/
            js/bundle.js
            css/bundle.css
            media/ *all my images*
```

All the images are extracted fine and work except for the images extracted from the css like :

```
cursor: url(../assets/myImage.png)
```

It is copied to the right folder `static/media/myImage.png`

but the url in the css points to `static/css/static/media/myImage.png`

Here is my webpack config for prod :

```
entry: {
    app: path.join(__dirname, 'src/App.js'),
    vendor: ["react", "react-dom"],
  },
  output: {
    path: "./build/",
    filename: 'static/js/[name].[chunkhash:8].js',
    chunkFilename: 'static/js/[name].[chunkhash:8].chunk.js'
  },

  module: {
    loaders: [
      {
        test: /\.sass$/,
        loader: ExtractTextPlugin.extract('style', 'css?-autoprefixer!postcss!sass')
      },
      {
        test: /\.(jpg|png|svg)(\?.*)?$/,
        loader: 'file',
        query: {
          name: 'static/media/[name].[hash:8].[ext]'
        }
      },
    ]
  },
  plugins: [
    new ExtractTextPlugin('static/css/[name].[contenthash:8].css',
   {allChunks: true}, {publicPath: './'})
  ]
};
```

The css is extracted to `static/css` but when it extracts the images it nests the paths in the code so instead of pointing to `static/media/` it gets nested and produces `static/css + static/media`

How can I get the correct path in my css ?

Thank you.

Comment: Is it fine on your development & other environments ?

Comment: Yes, since the url path is correct they display fine, I'm probably missing something silly but I can't figure it out, thanks for your help.

Comment: If the URL path is correct & working on your development, it should work in prod as well because they use the same webpack config right ? Also in webpack there will be a config to determine the environments as well, can you check that & paste that code as well.

Comment: Correct path in dev does not mean correct path in prod since the paths are handles by webpack when it extracts the assets. And my environment is set to prod as well.